# find the orthogonal projection of 1

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V = C[0,π/2]$ and consider the inner product $\langle ·, · \rangle  : V × V → R$ defined by

${\langle f,g\rangle} =\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(x)g(x)} dx$

for all $f, g ∈ V$. Find the orthogonal projection of $1$ onto $\text{span}({\cos(x),\sin(x)})$.

$\langle\cos(x), \sin(x)\rangle$

$\langle\cos(x), \cos(x)\rangle$

$\langle\sin(x), \sin(x)\rangle$

I'm pretty sure we need to use those to find the orthogonal projection of $1$. However, I am not quite sure how to do it

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're given the definition of the inner product. To find the inner product of two functions, you take that defining formula, replace $f$ with your first function, replace $g$ with your second function, and compute the integral. Is the problem that you're unable to do the integration?

Answer (score 0):

Applying the Gram-Schmidt process to $\{\sin,\cos\}$, you will get that an orthonormal basis of $\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{\sin,\cos\}\bigr)$ is $\{f_1,f_2\}$, with$$f_1(x)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\sin(x)\text{ and }f_2(x)=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi(\pi^2-4)}}\bigl(\pi\cos(x)-2\sin(x)\bigr).$$So, the orthogonal projection $p_1$ that you're after is $\langle1,f_1\rangle f_1+\langle1,f_2\rangle f_2$; in other words, it is the function$$p_1(x)=\frac{4\bigl(\sin (x)+\cos (x)\bigr)}{2+\pi}.$$

Comment: Why apply Gram-Schmidt process to {sin, cos} and not {cos, sin}?

Comment: No special reason. The final answer will be the same anyway.

Comment: sorry for 5 day late, I just do the Gram-Schmidt process and couldn't get the same answer as your.what inner product did you use?

Comment: $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^{\pi/2}{f(x)g(x)}\mathrm dx$

Comment: so f and g is cos(x) and sin(x)?

Comment: The functions $f$ and $g$ can be any elements of $C\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: you said we need to apply Gram-Schmidt process to {cos x, sin x}.  suppose what you mean is  $\sqrt{\int_0^{\pi/2}{sin(x)cos(x)}} dx$ is the first step?

Comment: No. In the first place, at no point I wrote that you (or I) *needed* to do whatever. In the second place, what I wrote was that I was applying the Gram-Schmidt process to $\{\sin,\cos\}$.